# Accessing buttons outside the form C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouseevent, mouselistener

i'm a newbie in C#. My boss has asked me to get co-ordinates of cursor when it's over some button **outside the form** (e.g on Desktop or any other random Window, like below).

[image: An OK button on Desktop]

I will then have to access the button properties for some computations (e.g width and height of button or it's name). I'm not sure if it's possible, my boss says it is as he's done something like that in the past. Gave me a hint that it can be done by knowing if the element is clickable and that there's an API for it. Thanks in advance!

Code Below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string label2Y;
        public string label1X;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
            label2.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
            label4.Text = Cursor.Position.Y.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Comment: [AutomationElement.FromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.frompoint)

Comment: `Form.MouseMove` is restricted to the current Form of the current Application. [WindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint) / [ChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint) can only return handles, so windowless controls are not detected. You should hook the Mouse (to receive mouse events generated outside your application).

Comment: @Salf, It will be very hard for us to do it. First, I can not find a mousehover event outside the form. Second, we also don't have API to distinguish which element is button.